# Can I access a SessionScoped CDI bean from a created Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a web application that has a `SessionScoped` bean which does a little bit of work. On my JSF page I have a button that I want the client to be able to push and have the progress of the work updated by `AJAX` on the page.

My idea to solve this was to create a new class that implements Runnable that calls the business method of my SessionScoped bean. I hooked up the submit button on the JSF page to a RequestScoped bean that creates a new Thread and starts my Runnable.

The problem with this approach is that the **member variables of the SessionScoped bean need to be updated by the new Thread**. Here's what I've tried.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Worker
{
  public workMethod();
}


@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Submitter
{
  @Inject
  private Worker worker;

  public startWork()
  {
    (new Thread(Runner(this.worker))).start();
  }
}




public class Runner implements Runnable
{
  private Worker worker = null;

  public Runner(Worker w)
  {
    this.worker = w;
  }

  public start()
  {
    this.worker.workMethod();
  }
}
```

This results in a WELD error when I try to call the workMethod:
`org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`

I'm using `Glassfish 3.1` , `Java EE 6`. I'm just trying to figure out my way through this and not create trouble for myself.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to recreate the wheel, there are dozens of components that already do this for you almost without code. See for instance: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml

Comment: That's not quite what I'm attempting to do but it is close. The problem with that approach is that you will only ever get 2 states: before and after; because all the work is happening in the same thread. I don't believe you can get updates on a running processing without using concurrency.